# Automated ACL Check in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, acl

I'd like to get some ideas from you on how to implement that. Let me explain a little bit my problem:

Scenario:
We have a system that must have some especific ACLs set in order to run it. So, before running it would be great if I could run a sort of pre check in order to verify if everything was set correctly.

Goal:
Create a script that checks those ACLs before starting the system alerting in case one of them is wrong based in a list of files/folder and its ACLs.

Problems:
Since the getfacl result is not a simple return, the only way I found to do such checking was parsing the result and analising each piece of it, that not as elegant as I'd like it could be.

I doubt many of you had to do something ACLs check but for sure you guys can contribute to my cause :)

Thanks everybody in advance

Comment: To run pre-check you need a copy of working ACL somewhere right?

Comment: yes Satish! But, as I said to larsks in the answer below, doesn't mather if it has more grants that the minimum required to run. In this case a simple comparison using a copy to an specific file wouldn't work. but please go ahead, I'm just supposing that your would suggest that :)

Comment: Simple way is get output of getfacl and modify according your need and just compare against where you installing apps.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Python` module `pylibacl`

```
>>> import posix1e
>>> acl1 = posix1e.ACL(file="file1.txt")
>>> print acl1
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Comment: Interesting ... That's new for me! Can you point me out some good documentation of it?

Comment: Here is a example script: https://github.com/iustin/pylibacl/blob/master/test/test_acls.py

Answer (score 1):

> Since the getfacl result is not a simple return, the only way I found to do such checking was parsing the result and analising each piece of it, that not as elegant as I'd like it could be.

What exactly are you trying to do?  If you're just comparing the result of calling `getfacl` to a desired ACL, it should be easy.  For example, assuming that you have stored your desired ACL in a file named `acl-i-want`, you could do something like this:

```
   getfacl /path > acl-i-have
   if ! diff -q acl-i-have acl-i-want; then
      echo "ACLs are different."
   fi
```

Comment: Not so easy ... supouse we have more ACLs (need read but it has also execute permissions) than the minimum necessary to run that application? In this case the check result should be OK.